# using sax as getter and setter

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sax

I need to use sax parser for getting multiple buttons name at android and save it in a file, and in some cases if I do make any changes that should be setted (loaded) to button text. 
Forexample:

**Button1 text is: life is good;
Button2 text is: life is not good**

"Button1,life is good; Button2, life is not good" should saved in a log.txt .
if I do any changes in that log.txt file like(possible to make update): "Button1,life quite good; Button2, life not wellcome", than

**Button1 text is: life quite good;
Button2 text is: life not wellcome**

so, how can I make it works, thank you.

Comment: This is just sample original one is bigger.

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: It is about about 30 buttons for now, it has possibilities to be more than 100.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this: You can use string resources. [String Resources | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

```
<resources>
    <string name="life_is_x">Life is %s</string>
    <string name="good">good</string>
    <string name="not_good">not good</string>
    <string name="quite_good">quite good</string>
</resources>
```

In your layout XML, you don't need to put a value for attribute `android:text` on your button (although if you specify `tools:text` the value will show in the Android Studio graphical layout designer only and not in your app, which is useful for designing.)

Then in your code:

```
    Context context = button.getContext();
    String lifeStr;
    switch (lifeEnum) {
    case GOOD:
        lifeStr = context.getString(R.string.good);
        break;
    case NOT_GOOD:
        lifeStr = context.getString(R.string.not_good);
        break;
    case QUITE_GOOD:
        lifeStr = context.getString(R.string.quite_good);
        break;
    }
    String title = context.getString(R.string.life_is_x, lifeStr);
    // lifeStr will replace the %s placeholder in life_is_x
    button.setText(title);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, I am allready using resources file. Problem is I need to make program to remember last text and possible to make changes at text too, any idea for that?

Comment: Do you mean in an Android app on the device, or in a standalone Java program during development?

Comment: I mean an android device. So, I think  sax xml setter to file might help me to store last text with button ID and in any case like program restarted it is possible to load button text if exist. Any clue how to that?

Comment: Here's the thing: You specify all those resources like layouts and strings and drawables in XML, but then the resources are compiled into the app in a machine format, so you can't parse them with an XML parser.  Whatever it is you are trying to do, you can most likely do it with string resources and some runtime logic.

Comment: I suppose if I may create a local xml file with proper tags that stores my variables, it is possible to achieve.

Comment: You could do that, then you should look into `XmlPullParser` which might be a little easier to use than SAX.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with jdom parser, actually I used this site: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_jdom_parse_document.htm
Also this link to create xml file: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_create_document.htm. Thank you for giving me ideas. I am recommending to any one who want to play with xml operation in local android device should give a look at to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/. you may find any kind of xml example..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
   <student rollno="393">
      <firstname>dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>kad</lastname>
      <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
      <nickname>vinni</nickname>
      <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="593">
      <firstname>jasvir</firstname>
      <lastname>singn</lastname>
      <nickname>jazz</nickname>
      <marks>90</marks>
   </student>
</class>


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.jdom2.Attribute;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

public class JDomParserDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         File inputFile = new File("input.txt");

         SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();

         Document document = saxBuilder.build(inputFile);

         System.out.println("Root element :" 
            + document.getRootElement().getName());

         Element classElement = document.getRootElement();

         List<Element> studentList = classElement.getChildren();
         System.out.println("----------------------------");

         for (int temp = 0; temp < studentList.size(); temp++) {    
            Element student = studentList.get(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" 
               + student.getName());
            Attribute attribute =  student.getAttribute("rollno");
            System.out.println("Student roll no : " 
               + attribute.getValue() );
            System.out.println("First Name : " + student.getChild("firstname").getText());
            System.out.println("Last Name : "+ student.getChild("lastname").getText());
            System.out.println("Nick Name : "+ student.getChild("nickname").getText());
            System.out.println("Marks : "+ student.getChild("marks").getText());                        
         }
      }catch(JDOMException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }catch(IOException ioe){
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```